# Microsoft JScript runtime error about ASPxUploadControl

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASPxUploadControl to add document. At first, it was working fine, but now I set its visibility to false, because of some reason. It gives me this error:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'myUploadControl' is undefined